# C# - Outlook - get access to a new calendar

Tags: c#, calendar, outlook

I am trying to read all the calendars I have in my outlook with C#, but i have a problem getting access to the ones I create inside outlook (right click -> new calendar).

I'm trying to get them by:

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MAPIFolder folderss =   ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
```

or by:

```
Application.Session.Stores
```

but none of them holds my new calendar.

do you have an Idea how to reach them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calendars are just `Folders` with `DefaultItemType` `OlItemType.olAppointmentItem`.
They can be created in any of the Outlook `Stores` on any level of the `Folder` hierarchy.

Assuming that the calendar was created in the root folder of one of your `Stores`, the following `C#` code will find it:

```
 void findMyCalendar(String name)
    {
        string path = null;

        Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");

        //  there may be more than one Store
        //  each .ost and .pst file is a Store
        Outlook.Folders folders = ns.Folders;

        foreach (Outlook.Folder folder in folders)
        {
            Outlook.MAPIFolder root = folder;
            path = findCalendar(root, name);

            if (path != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show(path ?? "not found!");
    }

//  non-recursive search for just one level
public string findCalendar(MAPIFolder root, string name)
    {
        string path = null;

        foreach (Outlook.MAPIFolder folder in root.Folders) 
        {
            if (folder.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                (folder.DefaultItemType == OlItemType.olAppointmentItem))
            {
                path = folder.FolderPath;
                break;
            }
        }

        return path;
    }
```